# Non consecutive combinations of array elements in R

Tags: r

I want to generate all the possible combinations of nonadjacent elements in an array.

For example:

```
array_a <- c("A","B","C")
```

possible combinations would be : `AC` and `CA`

How can I implement this in R?

Comment: How do you define non-adjacent elements?  It is not clear.

Answer (score 5):

If nonadjacent elements are defined as elements with distance greater than one in absolute values, then one option could be:

```
mat <- which(as.matrix(dist(seq_along(array_a))) > 1, arr.ind = TRUE)
paste0(array_a[mat[, 1]], array_a[mat[, 2]])

 [1] "CA" "DA" "EA" "DB" "EB" "AC" "EC" "AD" "BD" "AE" "BE" "CE"
```

Sample data:

```
array_a <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
```

Comment: Nice interpretation, I like the usage of dist function.

Comment: maybe I'm missing something... shouldn't the paste part be just: `paste0(array_a[mat[,1]], array_a[mat[,2]])` ?

Comment: @Edo good point, it is much more elegant, thanks :)

Comment: Cool to use `dist`, +1!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `outer`

```
c(outer(array_a, array_a, FUN = paste, sep=""))
```

---

Or if we want to omit alternate elements

```
outer(array_a[c(TRUE, FALSE)], array_a[c(TRUE, FALSE)], FUN = paste, sep="")
```

---

Or using `crossing`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
crossing(v1 = array_a[c(TRUE, FALSE)], 
         v2 = array_a[c(TRUE, FALSE)]) %>%
     filter(v1 != v2) %>% 
     unite(v1, v1, v2, sep="") %>% 
     pull(v1)
#[1] "AC" "CA"
```

NOTE: It is not clear about the assumptions for non-adjacent elements.  We answered it based on a different assumption.

Comment: The `outer` option is brilliant, +1!

Comment: You get the down-vote from me as your solution is incorrect in my opinion. It is incorrect for a short vector and the longer one too. When I got here I see your answers with +1 vote and @tmfmnk with zero of them. For me it is obvious that his solution is a right one.

Comment: @polkas thanks for the comments to clear that.  Have a great day!  As I mentioned in the comments, the question is not very clear because the nonadjacent part is not clear

Comment: @polkas I think it would be better to comment rather than just to give a down-vote without telling a reason. That would help to improve the answers.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding it's okay for the downvote.  I was only surprised at the timing though.  I am not worried about imaginary points :=)

Comment: I will be remember that. This sounds reasonable to inform sb about the reasons too in any case. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The @tmfmnk solution is so cool. Still I want to add sth from me.
I use the `arrangements` package for permutations without repetition.

```r
array_a <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
#vec to rm from permutations neighbors
vec = paste0(array_a[-1], head(array_a, -1))
cc = apply(arrangements::permutations(array_a, 2, replace = F), 1, function(x) paste0(x, collapse = ""))
> setdiff(cc, c(vec, stringi::stri_reverse(vec)))                             
  [1] "AC" "AD" "AE" "BD" "BE" "CA" "CE" "DA" "DB" "EA" "EB" "EC"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `expand.grid` + `subset`

```
inds <- subset(expand.grid(seq_along(array_a), seq_along(array_a)), abs(Var1 - Var2) > 1)
paste0(array_a[inds$Var1],array_a[inds$Var2])
```